# Rails cancan gem for not restfull controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Is it possible to use cancan load_and_authorize_resource for Controller with different name then model?

I mean:

> Controller name -> EntityPropertiesController
>
> Model name -> Property

Answer (score 1):

I don't found good way. So there is work around solution

```
class EntityPropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    check_permission
  end

  def new
    check_permission
    ...
  end

  def create
    check_permission
    ...
  end

  ...

  protected

  def check_permission
    not_found unless (current_user.admin? || current_user.moderator?)
  end
end
```